# Images too scattered

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have the following code (as part of a bigger document):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{ifpdf,eurosym,amstext}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\yenrule{\rule{1.3ex}{.1ex}}

\def\textyen{\renewcommand\stacktype{L}\stackon[.4ex]{\stackon[.65ex]{Y}{\yenrule}}{\yenrule}}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\rule{18.35cm}{0.1pt}
\break \break \break

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{SPX}
\caption*{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{FTSE}
\caption*{}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The two images appear too separated, I would like them to appear side by side. If I remove "\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}" they're next to another, but in the middle of the page. Any help on this?

Comment: If you want them next to each other, try to remove the `\hfill`

Comment: Why are your images much larger then the minipages you try to squeeze them into? And what is the purpose of `\break \break \break`?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Output of the code, showing images beside one another]

I had no trouble with the simpler code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{2-conics}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{2-conics}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps you could clarify the need for the other lines of code in your example.

If you want to label the two figures independently, you might use the subcaption package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{9cm}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{2-conics}
\caption{A pair of conics}
\label{fig:pair.1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{9cm}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{2-conics}
\caption{Another pair of conics}
\label{fig:pair.2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The minipages appears to because each image should have a separate caption.